# obj-c : Cant change subView of viewcontroller with Notification

Tags: objective-c

I'm confused about below situation. 
I have a viewcontroller(VC), it has 1 subview(SubV) and 1 other class.(classA)
Also i have an event handler called from classA, i want this event handler to change my subV in VC.

When i access SubV from VC directly, it is OK, image of subview changed etc.
But when the classA triggers an event handler of VC, it reaches VC, also access subView's method but no change in my subView !!! (I also try delegate but the result is same)

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
.
IBOutlet SubView *subView;
ClassA *classA;
.
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet SubView *subView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) ClassA *classA;
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
self.subView = [self.subView init];
self.classA = [[ClassA alloc] init];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(eventListener:) name:@"eventType" object:nil];

}

- (void) eventListener:(NSNotification *) not
{
   [self.subView RefreshView]; // it doesnt work! calls refreshView method but no change
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{ 
   [self.subView RefreshView]; // it works perfect
}
```

SubView.h

```
@interface SubView : UIImageView 

@property int state;
@property NSArray *imageArray;

- (void) RefreshView;
- (id) init;

@end
```

SubView.m

```
- (void) RefreshView{
[self stopAnimating];
self.imageArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"], nil];
self.animationDuration = 1;   
self.animationImages = self.imageArray;
self.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[self startAnimating];
}
```

ClassA.m

```
-(void)methodA{
  [myEvent requestEvent];
}
```

So, what i am trying to do here is accessing & changing subView with a button in Viewcontroller and with a thread running in another classA

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. For starters, this line of code is almost certainly wrong: `self.subView = [self.subView init];`

Comment: I agree, it sounds wrong, but when i run [self.subView RefreshView] it works....i also try self.subView = [[UIimageview alloc] init]; and after that when i call [self.subView RefreshView]; it doesnt work..

Comment: There's not enough information here to know why that's the case.

Comment: What exactly does your startAnimating method do?

Comment: For many cases it switches(animates) images of subView. For example for case 1: switch between a&b images, for case 2: switch between c,d,e images...

Comment: The thing is you, confirm that the eventListener calls the refreshView method. So obviously the error is not with the notification. You set an image, and some variables that has to do with some animation, but you don't let us see what you actually do with these variables afterwards... Could you please show the startAnimating method as well.

Comment: What i am trying to do here is accessing & changing subView with a button in Viewcontroller and with a thread running in another classA.

Comment: Firstly thanks for your quick replies, @nickfalk: startAnimating Method is not my own method, not sure but i think UIImageView's method  .

Comment: There is a class-method beginAnimations:context and commitAnimations but there are no instance-method called startAnimating on UIView to the best of my knowledge...

Comment: Actually, startAnimating is exist and no problem with this method, when i call subView method's directly from view controller, everything is ok...i guess it is about self.subView initialization, i should alloc first but why it doesnt work if i call self.subView = [[UIimageview alloc] init]; ????

Comment: Ah, right so it's an UIImageView, didn't catch that sorry. However if I understand you correctly you've subclassed UIImageView into a class you've called SubView, is that correct?

Comment: Exactly, sorry for misinformation :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i've found the solution! Because of the thread that i run in ClassA, i should use '

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(myMethodToRefreshSubView) withObject:nil    waitUntilDone:NO];
```

in my eventListener method.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Not quite sure what to make of this. You've edited your post to the changes I proposed, making my answer look superfluous at best and deranged at worst...

You have created the class SubView as a subclass of UIImageView. But the IBOutlet *subView is not a member of class SubView but a member of UIImageView. I suspect this might carry over to the xib/storyboard as well(?) If so, this means that any messages you send to your subView instance will be handled by a stock UIImageView rather than your own class...

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *subView;
```

should probably read

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet SubView *subView;
```

Comment: Whether the outlet is declared as a `UIImageView` or as a subclass thereof doesn't matter for the question which class handles the messages sent to it. It matters what type the *instance* assigned to that property actually has. For what it's worth, you could change all your properties to have the type `id`, without changing any actual behavior.

Comment: @nickfalk I've updated my question part (SubView.h is added)...I tried your suggestion but still doesnt work :( _italic_ "This means that any messages you send to your subView instance will be handled by a stock UIImageView rather than your own class"_italic_  i suspect this too but i couldnt find the solution yet :(

Comment: @omz As it is an IBOutlet it stands to reason that it is inited from a xib, I figured that since the Class-name was wrong in the viewController's header this was a strong indication that the xib is not hooked up to his own class either...

Comment: @jaco Have you checked you xib? Have you checked that the class in the identity inspector is SubView rather than UIImageView?

Comment: @nickfalk I've just checked the identity inspector and yes it is SubView.

Comment: @omz could you please give an example to all properties with the type id? Because i directly call the method of SubView(refreshView) from ViewController.

Comment: OK, back to the drawing-board then. Where do you set the initial image? (In the RefreshView you always create the same imageArray with one single image).

Comment: I set the initial image on storyboard, not programatically...actually i didnt put the whole refreshView content, in refreshView; i control the 'state' and for each 'state' case i put some images to the same array then i call the startAnimated method.

Comment: And how/where do you set this state?

Comment: in ViewController...like self.SubView.state = X...but i checked the state value and it is correct...i also debug the SubView instance, for both with button control & notification it points the same address in memory...i couldnt understand what is the problem.

Comment: Finally i've found the solution! Because of the thread that i run in ClassA, i should use '[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(myMethodToRefreshSubView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];' in my eventListener method..it works...thank you everyone especially nickfalk.